# Calculate mean of sample size based on relative frequency in histogram

Tags: distributions, sample-size, histogram, frequency

I have the following data of number of vouchers redeemed :

[image]

How can i calculate the mean value of total vouchers?

Comment: You don't have information for computing the total.  By "mean value of total vouchers" shall we presume you mean the *arithmetic mean of the value*?  If so, please see the duplicate.

Comment: i don't have the N that's what is questioned... i also am not seeing how can i answer this but it is an excercise and it's just as it is here...

Comment: Some of the mean values listed in the third column do not fall within the range of values in the first column.  Can you explain this apparent incongruity?

Comment: sorry, i will update is not correct

Answer (score 0):

Do you know how many vouchers were sold in total?

If so - and if I understood the problem correctly - you could find the mean by
$\frac{(mean\_val\_vouch_1*\%\_vouchers_1*total\_vouchers)+(mean\_val\_vouch_2*\%\_vouchers_2*total\_vouch)+...}{total\_vouchers}$

So in your case it would be
$\frac{(4*0*total+14*1*total+25*2*total+...+850*3*total)}{total}$

You're basically reconstructing the number of items in each line by multiplying the % with the total, and the rest of the formula is the traditional combined mean (see e.g. https://www.statisticshowto.com/combined-mean/)

Comment: I don't...but i need right? i just have this information and that's why i asked here because either i am not aware how is this done or the exercise doesn't have all the information, at least at my point of view

Comment: btw, mean value is in € so it's the midpoint

Comment: That's incorrect: the midpoints of the bins are at 5, 15, 25, *etc.*  The mean value is the *sum of the numbers in each bin divided by their bin count.*  This is crucial for the last (unlimited) bin, *which has no midpoint.*  Nevertheless, from the means and the percentages you can recover the overall mean *exactly* (at least up to the precision with which the data are displayed) using the duplicate answer.  You don't need to know the total.